# How to scroll through whole images in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for some code which allows to scroll just through whole images on my landing page.

I don't really know how to explan but it's exactly the style on tesla.com. Every scroll on the mousewheel scrolls down one whole image.

How can you make something like this in Css & Javascript?

Best regards,
andy

Comment: It's probably some sort of [vertical slider like this](https://smartslider3.com/fullsize/). Maybe you could use that?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can find bunch of working code around, but if you want to create your own you can follow these steps to begin.

1. Create divs with 100% width and height and `position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0; transform:translateY(100%)`.
2. Your divs will need some status flags like active, hidden, next, prev. Create animations with css or javascript which visually animate the divs but also change and handle these flags.

   i.e. `transform:translateY(0);` to show a div and `transform:translateY(100%);` to hide a div back again. (This animations are completely up to you)
3. Finally bind these animation to window scroll event with javascript. If you want you can't bind these to other events like keypress, touch etc.

Answer (score -1):

Now, I got it, what you want you use in your app.
You want to scroll through the whole page with an multiple image in the background should be changed on-scroll. 
It can be done nicely using `background-image` property in `CSS` some `Javascript`.

See this demo - [Change background image on-scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bg_change_scroll.asp).
Use this, it will work like charm.

Comment: The Background image shouldn't be fixed. It should change every mousscroll down. Normally, when you scroll down, it scrolls down about 10px. but i want to scroll down until the next full image is shown completely.

Comment: not exactly like that. check out the tesla.com website and scroll down. this is the effect i want to achieve...